# SpringBoot web-socket without stomp

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

Tries to create an web application based on spring boot with web-socket support
Define public static main class annotated with @SpringBootApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Facade {

public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {
    Map<String,Object> contextProperties = new HashMap<>();
    contextProperties.put("server.port",p.getProperty("server.port","8091"));
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Facade.class);
    app.setDefaultProperties(contextProperties);
    app.run(argv);
    }
}
```

Add configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new SocketTextHandler(), "/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

Add handler

```
@Component
public class SocketTextHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws IOException {
        String payload = message.getPayload();
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Hi " + payload + " how may we help you?"));
    }


    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Connected!"));

    }
}
```

There are maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.31</version>
    </dependency>
```

spring boot version is 2.5.5

When I connect to socket using JavaScript

```
webSocket = new WebSocket(wsUrl);
```

I see in app logs
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.server.HandshakeFailureException: **Servlet request failed to upgrade to WebSocket**: http://127.0.0.1:8091/ws; nested exception is javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException] with **root cause**
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeInfo**

The tomcat-coyote dependency is in pom.xlm

I used web-sockets in jersey implementation under tomcat9. Now I tries to migrate application to spring-boot, but confused with NoClassDef exception.

Could you please explain or suggest solution for this cause.

Comment: Remove the coyote dependency all necessary dependencies are already pulled in with the `spring-boot-starter-websocket` dependency.

Comment: @M.Deinum this dependency do not take any effect. The exception is the same
with dependency 
or
with out.

dependency was removed from.pom

But the web-socket still does not work

Comment: This is weird as the test for this in Spring Boot does the same, so you must be doing something else/weird that throws things off. Can you include your dependencies you use?

Comment: change version for 

    tomcat-embeded-core from 9.0.31 to 9.0.55 
    add tomcat-embeded-websocket the same version 
    and switch to spring-boot:2.0.6 


And this fix issue for me

Comment: @M.Deinum Just to clarify the situation: I design a complicate software application with root pom(it does not inherit the spring-boot). The issue was in one of chlidren for my suer-pom. In children I add dependency for spring-boot-starter-web and -startter-web-socket. I belive, that spring super pom includes dependency for tomcat embeded(I see difference version of tomcat, when switheng the provided version in my super-pom). Adding the same version tomcat-embed-websocket resolve the issue. But I did not try to make it as provided.

Comment: @M.Deinum The open question is: how can I define ecplicetelly the handler for web socket, I mean to reconfigure to use smth else, not tomcat's UpgradeInfo

Comment: You should use the version that matches your servlet container, else it won't work. You need your container to support web sockets as well.